# Get the root View of UIButton pressed

Tags: ios, asynchronous

In the main screen of my application I have a button to update the SQLite database on my device. This upgrade do with the outer class:

```
-(IBAction)updateData:(id)sender{

        SQLManager *sqlmgr =[[SQLManager alloc]init];
            [sqlmgr createDB];

}
```

The problem is I want to display a progress dialog MBProgressHUD but if released from updateData event runs just 1 second and when I called the method still working away.

Inside SQLManager createDB Method, I run 5 async Tasks. These is the reason why I need show a Dialog Progress

The only thing that occurred to me is to call the method I call, but I like picking up from where the button is pressed to put in the parameter of method showing MBProgressHUD, but I don't know how...

```
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Cargando";
    SQLManager *sqlmgr =[[SQLManager alloc]init];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:??????????? animated:YES];
```

Comment: If your updateData: method is in the same UIViewController as the button, you can just use self.view. Otherwise, sender is your button, so you can call superView on it and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Your application has a thread generally referred to as the main thread or the UI thread. If you block this thread then any UI will be halted until the process on that thread has been completed. As such this is normally considered a bad idea.

You need to run your process on a different thread. Grand Central Dispatch is one method of doing so.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

With it your code could would look like this

```
-(IBAction)updateData:(id)sender{


    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //Call your function or whatever work that needs to be done
    //Code in this part is run on a background thread
     SQLManager *sqlmgr =[[SQLManager alloc]init];
        [sqlmgr createDB];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) 
    {

         //Stop your activity indicator or anything else with the GUI
        //Code here is run on the main thread
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried it and the problem is that the thread is not closed ... and MBProgressHUD still running.

Comment: I understand that the code that you have recommended to me, at the end of the method [sqlmgr createDB] should hide the MBProgressHUD, right? Well the problem is not hiding, so I do not understand that the method detects finished.

Comment: updated according to the MBProgressHUD documentation.

Comment: Ok, making these, the MBProgressHUD apear and desapear in 1 second and the method [sqlmgr createdDB]; still runs

Comment: does createDB run an asynchronous process? If so you need to do something to be aware of when that process has completed.

Comment: I explain better.I've an Application which has 2 classes (ViewController and SQLManager), the first of which is the class that inherits from UIViewController and in whose view I've a button. Clicking this button executes the createDB method, which is within the SQLManager (NSObject), therefore, I create an object of type SQLManager (sqlmgr) and I call the method createDB inside the IBAction of the button. Within createDB asyncronos I throw several actions (get data from a webservice, download pictures, stores data in SQLite).I need when finish all asyncronos methods, MBProgressHUD disappears.